# Eclipse IDE plugin development: copy files from plugin jar to active project folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plug-in for eclipse. The purpose of the plug-in is to generate code by using Acceleo.

I want to copy the contents of a directory from the generator plug-in jar, into the folder where files have been generated after the plug-in has finished generating the code.

org.plugin.generator/framework
 ||
copy contents to:
 ||
 \/
Workspace/ProjectFolder/generatedFiles/classes

I can get the paths, but I can't figure out how to extract the framework folder from the jar and copy its contents in the current project folder.

Can anyone please provide some tips? I am a beginner at Eclipse plug-in development.
Also, this is my first question here, although I have been browsing for 1-2 years.

Comment: Getting the path to the jar is the hard part, as far as working in an Eclipse plugin; after that, you could just extract the files you need with java.util.ZipInputStream. What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rough code snippet to read any file from a plugin and write it to a project. I do not know if there is a way to list files in a bundle folder, but you can always hardcode the list of files you need to copy.

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle( "your.plugin.id" );
InputStream stream = FileLocator.openStream( bundle, "path.in.plugin", false );
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject( "your.project" );
IFile file = project.getFile( "something/abc.txt" );
file.create( stream, true, null );
```

You will need to add exception handling and closing of the stream to the above snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have managed to solve the problem by using this: File f = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(Platform.getBundle("pluginID").getEntry("/")).toURI());

Comment: Don't recommend doing it that way as it ties you to having exploded plugins in production as opposed to the recommended way of deploying plugins as jars. The API that I showed will work either way.