# Eclipse PDE development: how to copy files from plugin to active folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm in the middle of developing a PDE in eclipse and I got stuck with a problem.
The problem is that I want to copy files from my plugin folder to the new active application folder and I don't know I my code will work because I don't to make my plugin a jar already and I need a working solution if someone has.
I found this solution [copy files with bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756218/eclipse-ide-plugin-development-copy-files-from-plugin-jar-to-active-project-fol) but it doesn't seem to work for me, I'm using this function to copy files from place to place is it enough?

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: At least you should use >= 0 with read(...).
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {

Comment: See http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/ - working code: https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx.ui/src/net/sf/pacx/ui/NewCorpusProjectOperation.java#l61

Comment: @howlger I think that it worked but how do i know it will completely work when ill pack my plugin?

Comment: The linked example is code from me, which I know that it works in a plug-in packed as a JAR. [Just don't forget to add the template files to `build.properties`](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx.ui/build.properties#l8).

Comment: @howlger I'll try it thanks

Comment: @howlger how can I copy .exe files because the copy you gave me harming the files. I need to copy them from a plug-in to the active folder

Comment: The copy should not harm binary files (it operates on an `InputStream` without text encoding). Please check if the templates files in the plug-in JAR  are already harmed.

Comment: @howlger not they are not harmed

Comment: Strange. Can you show your code?

Comment: @howlger
private void createFile(String filePath, File dest, boolean isAnExe) {
  URL url;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
  ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
   url = new URL("platform:/plugin/" + filePath);

   InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(inputLine);
   }

Comment: if (!isAnExe) {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dest);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for (String s : lines)
     out.write(s + "\n");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
   } else {
    Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
    bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    Files.write(path, bytes);
   }
   in.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
 }
@howlger

Comment: With Java 8 you can use for both, binary and text files `Files.copy(new URL("platform:/plugin/" + filePath).openStream(), Paths.get(filePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: @howlger i got this error message java.nio.file.FileSystemException: myFirstPlugin\templates\.microcodeTools\EZprep.exe: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I understand this that the target file already exists and is locked (e. g. because it is being executed) and therefore cannot be overwritten.

Comment: @howlger I'm not executing the file I just want to it and then afterwards to execute it

Comment: Is `myFirstPlugin\templates\.microcodeTools\EZprep.exe` the source or target file? Check if it is locked by trying to rename it.

Comment: @howlger that is the source file and to rename it to what?

Comment: Only temporarily e. g. to `EZprep2.exe`. If this is possible, it is not locked. What is your `filePath`, the symbolic name of the bundle/plug-in and the path inside the plug-in to the file?

Comment: @howlger 
filePath = "platform:/plugin/myFirstPlugin/templates/.microcodeTools/EZasm.exe"

symbolic name = "myfirstplugin" if im correctly remember

the path inside the plugin : "C:\Users\Nadav\Desktop\YD\Java\myFirstPlugin\templates\.microcodeTools\EZprep.exe"

Comment: @howlger its somehow worked now to change the name ill try to see if the copy works